# Alternative to paypal MEC library

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, paypal

In my company we are creating a platform (iOS, Android, Web) that accepts payments via PayPal.
For this we are implementat **Express checkout** of paypal.

Basically, the solution was implemented until Apple reject the application due to ***libPaypalEC.a*** (this uses the UID of the device.)

Once the web version and android run smoothly, is there any quick solution for iOS without the use of the library and any change in the API?
For example, is there any way to get the "drt" without being through the use of the library?

**PayPal SDK** and **MPL** are not a solution to my problem, since I find myself in a non U.S. territory and require payment by credit card.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution provided by PayPal was to use the Express Checkout instead of the MEC. T only change is that the token(dtr) is sen t null. This library was discontinued by them because of the new Paypal´s SDK for mobile platforms.